# Use Regex with match to capture an activation sha1 code

Tags: javascript, regex, gmail, match

I´m making an google scritp to auto execute the activation links of the emails received from a platform.

I´m trying to figure how to capture in a variable the code at the end of the activation link, it is an sha1 hash.

The code i´m trying

```js
    if(msg.isInInbox()) {
        var link = msg.getBody().match(/<a href="http:\/\/myweb.es\/testing\/code\/confirm.php?active_link=\/([\w\d]+)"/);
        
        if(link) {
          var url = 'http://myweb.es/testing/code/confirm.php?active_link=' + link[1];
          var options = {
            "muteHttpExceptions": true
          };
```

But if i check the debug the link var is empty so something is wrong i guess with the regex code at the end of the match capture but i´ve never been good at regex so after hours driving me me mad i´m here asking.

EDIT TO INCLUDE EXAMPLE OF FULL URL:

http://myweb.es/testing/code/confirm.php?active_link=f9629b7d418315ea8f6e929d529d86cb7caf10cc

Comment: `?` is a special regex char and should be escaped. Same as a `.`, but `.` is not that critical here.

Comment: Thanks , i will check now if that is all the problem

Comment: You're capturing all characters till last " while using `(.+)`, some edits mentioned in my answer @JuanpePedro

Comment: SOLVED - there was a class before the href and that was all.  Now working thanks mohamad and all that helped

Answer (score 1):

Does this one works for you:

```
if(msg.isInInbox()) {
    var link = msg.getBody().match(/<a\s*href=("|')https?:\/\/myweb.es\/testing\/code\/confirm.php\?active_link=(.+?)\1/);

if(link) {
   var url = 'http://myweb.es/testing/code/confirm.php?active_link=' + link[2];
   var options = {
      "muteHttpExceptions": true
   };
}
```

- `\s*` added after`<a`
- `https?` for http/https matching
- `?` before the active_link was optional matching; changed to `\?` for special '?' character
- `active_link=\/` changed to `active_link=` because I don't think any activation link starts by `/` while you re-build `var url` without `\/`
- `?` added to capturing group `(.+?)` to stop at the end of `href` tag
- and `("|')` capturing group added after href= for supporting " and ' property definitions and reused by `\1` at the end of regex pattern.

**Note**: matched group for activation link is `link[2]` while [0] is whole matched string, [1] is " or ' and [2] is what you want.

Comment: Tried the solution proposed but the var link shows as null in the debugger.  I´m trying to findout now , Will update if i find why

Comment: can you paste html code of your activation link in your Question? @JuanpePedro , it's possible that your link has class or style before href property... we can remove `<a\s*` from starting of regex!

Comment: Amazing MohaMad ,  you´ve done it.  There was a class= just before the href= so changed it and its working :D  -  I give you my positive but it does not count because i´m new here

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please consider marking the solution as correct by clicking on the grey check below the vote buttons -- this removes it from the 'Unanswered Questions' queue, and awards reputation to both the question asker and question answerer. Of course, in saying that, you are under no obligation to mark an answer as correct, though it does help to keep things flowing smoothly, and you appear confident that this has solved your problem :)